# How to write callouts using reStructuredText?

Tags: restructuredtext, asciidoc

[Asciidoc](https://asciidoc.org) supports [callouts](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/verbatim/callouts/). How can one write similar callouts using [reStructuredText](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/rst.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does not seem to be a built-in equivalent, but it is easy to make something that looks similar to the example given in the asciidoc documentation:

```
.. topic:: MS-DOS directory listing

   ::

     10/17/97   9:04         <DIR>    bin
     10/16/97  14:11         <DIR>    DOS            <1>
     10/16/97  14:40         <DIR>    Program Files
     10/16/97  14:46         <DIR>    TEMP
     10/17/97   9:04         <DIR>    tmp
     10/16/97  14:37         <DIR>    WINNT
     10/16/97  14:25             119  AUTOEXEC.BAT   <2>
      2/13/94   6:21          54,619  COMMAND.COM    <2>
     10/16/97  14:25             115  CONFIG.SYS     <2>
     11/16/97  17:17      61,865,984  pagefile.sys
     2/13/94   6:21           9,349  WINA20.386      <3>

   1. This directory holds MS-DOS.
   2. System startup code for DOS.
   3. Some sort of Windows 3.1 hack.
```

The only thing this lacks is the highlights on the markers. If those are very important to you, you can use a `parsed-literal` block:

```
.. topic:: MS-DOS directory listing

   .. parsed-literal::

      10/17/97   9:04         <DIR>    bin
      10/16/97  14:11         <DIR>    DOS            **<1>**
      10/16/97  14:40         <DIR>    Program Files
      10/16/97  14:46         <DIR>    TEMP
      10/17/97   9:04         <DIR>    tmp
      10/16/97  14:37         <DIR>    WINNT
      10/16/97  14:25             119  AUTOEXEC.BAT   **<2>**
       2/13/94   6:21          54,619  COMMAND.COM    **<2>**
      10/16/97  14:25             115  CONFIG.SYS     **<2>**
      11/16/97  17:17      61,865,984  pagefile.sys
      2/13/94   6:21           9,349  WINA20.386      **<3>**

   1. This directory holds MS-DOS.
   2. System startup code for DOS.
   3. Some sort of Windows 3.1 hack.
```

Should you have very many of these callouts, then I suggest making a custom directive for them.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [parsed-literal](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#parsed-literal-block) block and the standard rST syntax for [footnotes](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#footnotes) or hyperlinks.